# jQuery append external css file to all HTML pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I have 2 different CSS files for 2 clients

If I select **option 1** from **indexer page**, all inside html pages should append below css file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/client1.css">`

or if I select **option 2**, then it should load below css file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/client2.css">`

**But, this change has to happen for all the html files which is under pages/**

> **Indexer.html**

```
<select class="selInput" id="selectClient">
    <option>-- Select Client --</option>
    <option value="client1">Client 1</option>
    <option value="client2">Client 2</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( document ).on( "change", "#selectClient", function(){
        jQuery(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="client1-script"){
                $("body").load("css/client1.css");
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="client2-script"){
                $("body").load("css/client2.css");
            }
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: why not include 2 of those files.  then just add or remove class on the `body` accordingly?

Comment: Do you even understand how `.load()` works?

Comment: Hi @Praveen Kumar... Sorry, that was just for demo.. I do not have much idea on script :(

Comment: Hi **@roullie**.. in that case, I want to class to **all html pages** which is under pages/ foler

Comment: @Reddy then you have to save the selected option somewhere.  database,session,cookies it's your choice.

Comment: @Reddy Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to do:

1. **Load Both CSS** and use classes to have difference in them.

   Consider `client1.css`:

   ```css
   body.client1 { /* rules */ }
   body.client1 h1 { /* rules */ }
   body.client1 p { /* rules */ }
   body.client1 ul,
   body.client1 ol { /* rules */ }
   ```

   Consider `client2.css`:

   ```css
   body.client2 { /* rules */ }
   body.client2 h1 { /* rules */ }
   body.client2 p { /* rules */ }
   body.client2 ul,
   body.client2 ol { /* rules */ }
   ```

   And in your HTML:

   ```
   <body class="client1"> <!-- if client 1 -->
   <body class="client2"> <!-- if client 2 -->
   ```

   In your JavaScript:

   ```
   $(function () {
       $("body").on("change", "#selectClient", function () {
           $("#body").removeClass("client1 client2").addClass("client" + $(this).val());
       });
   });
   ```
2. **Use a `<link />` with `id`** and change the `href`.

   In your `<head>`:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/client1.css" id="style" />
   ```

   In your JavaScript:

   ```
   $(function () {
       $("body").on("change", "#selectClient", function () {
           $("#style").attr("href", "css/client" + $(this).val() + ".css");
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: **@Praveen Kumar**... Thanks for your time, it is applying for only current page... but I want is: In **index.html**, If I select **client1** option, this page navigates to **client.html** page with "client1.css" file loaded.. and also remaining html pages also should load the **client1.css** file... Is it possible please?

Comment: @Reddy I suggest you go for this plugin: [`jQuery.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and set it when you change.

Comment: **@Praveen Kumar** Thanks again... will go through it, and upvote your answer as well :)...

Comment: @Reddy All the best then.